# Picture's width to be placed inside < div >

Tags: jquery, image, html, resizable

While resizing the picture, I want the picture width added to < div id="w" >< /div >, I have tried the following, anyone can help? thank you:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
         resize: select_function
    });
});
var select_function = function(event, ui)
{
    $("#w").text($( "#resizable" ).attr("width"));
};

</script>
 <div id="w">Test</div>
<img border="0" id="resizable" src="picture.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `width=""` attribute.

To get the actual width of the element, call `$( "#resizable" ).width()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting the width of the image like this?

```
$("#w").html($( "#resizable" ).width());
```

Comment: why the downvote??? It's the same answer as the others, but those answers were not here  when I started writing the post...

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add a `width` attribute to the `img` tag.

```
<img border="0" id="resizable" src="picture.png" width="500px">
```

Or you need to use the built-in JQuery `width()` function.

```
$( "#resizable" ).width();
```

I recommend checking out the JQuery docs on [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get a better understanding.